# how to create custom editor provider in ignite ui grid with angular js

Tags: angularjs, infragistics, ignite-ui, iggrid

I am using Ignite UI grid directive with angular js.
In that I am creating custom editor provider by extending `$.ig.EditorProvider`
and using that editor in html markup as

```
<column-setting column-key="comments" editor-provider="new $.ig.EditorProviderNumber()"> 
</column-setting>
```

but when I edit grid its showing error

```
provider.createEditor is not a function
```

plz help me

Comment: What's the Ignite UI version that you're using?
To get the version please execute the following code in the JavaScript console:
$.ui.igGrid.version

Answer (score 4):

Written this way the "editor-provider" value will be evaluated as string. In order for the expression to be parsed to an object you need to enclose it in `{{}}` (double curly braces). However the statement "new $.ig.EditorProviderNumber()" will not be parsed by the [Angular 1 expression parser](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression), so you need to use a scope function to create the object.

Here is the code:

```
// This editor provider demonstrates how to wrap HTML 5 number INPUT into editor provider for the igGridUpdating
$.ig.EditorProviderNumber = $.ig.EditorProviderNumber || $.ig.EditorProvider.extend({
    // initialize the editor
    createEditor: function (callbacks, key, editorOptions, tabIndex, format, element) {
        element = element || $('<input type="number" />');
        /* call parent createEditor */
        this._super(callbacks, key, editorOptions, tabIndex, format, element);

        element.on("keydown", $.proxy(this.keyDown, this));
        element.on("change", $.proxy(this.change, this));
        this.editor = {};
        this.editor.element = element;
        return element;
    },
    keyDown: function(evt) {
        var ui = {};
        ui.owner = this.editor.element;
        ui.owner.element = this.editor.element;
        this.callbacks.keyDown(evt, ui, this.columnKey);
        // enable "Done" button only for numeric character
        if ((evt.keyCode >= 48 && evt.keyCode <= 57) || (evt.keyCode >= 96 && evt.keyCode <= 105)) {
            this.callbacks.textChanged(evt, ui, this.columnKey);
        }
    },
    change: function (evt) {
        var ui = {};
        ui.owner = this.editor.element;
        ui.owner.element = this.editor.element;
        this.callbacks.textChanged(evt, ui, this.columnKey);
    },
    // get editor value
    getValue: function () {
        return parseFloat(this.editor.element.val());
    },
    // set editor value
    setValue: function (val) {
        return this.editor.element.val(val || 0);
    },
    // size the editor into the TD cell
    setSize: function (width, height) {
      this.editor.element.css({
            width: width - 2,
            height: height - 2,
            borderWidth: "1px",
            backgroundPositionY: "9px"
      });
    },
    // attach for the error events
    attachErrorEvents: function (errorShowing, errorShown, errorHidden) {
        // implement error logic here
    },
    // focus the editor
    setFocus: function () {
        this.editor.element.select();
    },
    // validate the editor
    validator: function () {
        // no validator
        return null;
    },
    // destroy the editor
    destroy: function () {
        this.editor.remove();
    }
});

sampleApp.controller('sampleAppCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.getProvider = function () {return new $.ig.EditorProviderNumber()};
});

<column-setting column-key="ProductNumber" editor-provider="{{getProvider()}}"></column-setting>
```

Comment: Once again, what's the Ignite UI version that you're using? To get the version please execute the following code in the JavaScript console: $.ui.igGrid.version

Comment: The [igGridUpdating.editorProvider](http://igniteui.com/help/api/2016.1/ui.iggridupdating#options:columnSettings.editorProvider) code snippet is not working in Ignite UI version 15.2 and up. I've added the source for the $.ig.EditorProviderNumber in my answer. Will create a case for the Ignite UI team to fix the code snippet.